# How to use <br> Tag within React map function loop

Tags: reactjs, arrays, loops, object, map-function

I loop through an Array of objects in ReactJS where I use map function to loop through each Object. So Can i use 
 tag to separate each objects in next line. I tried to put a 
 tag at the end of the loop but it does'nt work. Let me know what the correct way of using it. The code is as follows. Thanks in Advance!

```
import React from 'react'

const items = [{
  name: "EVC",
  price: 300
},{
  name: "JVN",
  price: 500
}]

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='items'>
      {items.map(item=> item.name + item.price+"<br>")}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: see this link https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-david-floqq2?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concentrate values, React escapes html tags for saftety. In your case `<br>` is treated as plain text, not html tag. If you really wanted to use it the way as in provided example, there is special prop  `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to output raw html.
However, it's better to add `<br>` directly using `<>` (shortcut for `React.Fragment`) to wrap your item data inside `map`. You can use `React.fragment` when you want to group items without rendering extra element in the DOM:

```
import React from 'react'
const items = [
  {
    name: "EVC",
    price: 300
  },
  {
    name: "JVN",
    price: 500
  }
];
            
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="items">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <>
          {item.name} {item.price} <br />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default App
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works as i expected. Can you also provide the technical explanation about how the fragment fix this issue. Because the map function is already comes inside a parent tag. So how the fragment really works here.

Comment: Yes, but you have to group your items inside map as well. You could have use plain `<div>` instead of `<>`, but it renders extra DOM and then `<br>` is redundant.  I added info to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `<br>` for space between paragraphs whenever you can.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='items'>
      {
      items.map((item, index) => {
       return(
        <div key={item + index} className="itemContainer">
            <p className="paragraph">{item.name + " " + item.price}</p> {/*Empty quotes are for space between the name and price*/}
        </div>
)
})
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

`<p></p>` has it's own line break so use it instead and use `margin` in your styles for more space if you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and suggestion you provide. Actually I was trying to figure out that why the <br> not works inside the map function. That is why I not vote for your answer. But I'll tick the 'usefull' answer. Thanks for your initiation and time that given me new knowledge